# install apache,php,mysql,zend in Ubuntu9.10

Tags: php, mysql, apache-2.2

I am php developer, but before now I write my project`s in windows os.
Now I study Linux(Ubuntu9.10) and I need your advise connected with php and zend.
I want to install php5,apache,mysql and zend but something is wrong.
Please help me to install php,apache,mysql and zend(by step please) or write useful links about it.
Thanks for any advise.

Answer (score 5):

You could start with the ubuntu website : [ApacheMySQLPHP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has a package manager called apt-get that will have everything you need, and it is a breeze.

From the ubuntu website: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Answer (score 0):

This is the right tutorial for you :
http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies